# One of the multiple sites hosted on IIS pointing to same path, app pool and useris not working

Tags: iis, web-hosting

We have multiple applications hosted under same site.

All these application point to same Path, App pools and Users.

These applications are accessed with different URLs.

Like, there are three applications A, B and C, out of which C is not accessible.

Site and Apps hosted on IIS:

[image: Site and Apps hosted on IIS]

All the sites were
working fine, but all of a sudden one of the site is done and displaying 403 error.

I have tried app pool recycle and providing full control permission to the application folder. But issue still exists.

I have compared basic settings of the sites and looks good.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis Learn more about that 403 before moving on.

Comment: I guess it is .net framework sites?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 403 ERROR occurs for multiple reasons,

1. Cached version of the site may cause 403. clear cache and check.
2. Most websites are configured to disallow directory browsing, so a 403 Forbidden message when trying to display a folder instead of a specific page, is normal and expected. if it's the case, enable directory browsing in your web server.
3. Permissions. Check whether your website has appropriate permissions.

Comment: thanks for your response. By clear cache, do mean browser cache?

Comment: yes or try in private mode.

Answer (score 0):

We could solve this, by creating a new shortcut folder of the main folder(folder pointed by the application - path) and updated the path of the application C to this new short cut folder.

It started working, application C is accessible.